# .map function re-rendering many times on page

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, frontend, mern

Problem: On the navbar, the tags should appear and then stay but when I run code it continuously moves from first to last, like 1st tag goes to 2nd, 2nd goes to 3rd and the loop continues never stops.

Frontend code (this code is already inside a return function):

```js
const Navbar = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/tags", {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setdata(data);
      });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-1">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div
            className="collapse navbar-collapse "
            id="navbarSupportedContent"
          >
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              {data.map((cats) => {
                return (
                  <li className="nav-item cats">
                    <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/c/post">
                      {cats._id}
                    </NavLink>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
//Link to={`/c/?cat=${cats._id}`}
```

Backend code:

```
router.get('/tags', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const categories = await Post.aggregate([
      { $project: { categories: 1 } },
      { $unwind: '$categories' },
      { $group: { _id: '$categories', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
      { $sort: { count: -1 } }
    ]);
    res.json(categories);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: where did you use this `{data.map ....}`? add this component. also, what is the result of your API call `/tags`, add the successful result to the question.

Comment: I can't see any piece of code related to API call, by seeing the code I can understand what would be the issue. try to add API call block @Prateek Nandle

Comment: `useEffect` with no dependancy array runs on every render, you should add an empty dependancy array to trigger `useEffect` once

Comment: you've forgotten to add an array of dependencies for your `useEffect` hook, so on every re-render, your API will be called which leads to an infinity API call. take a look at the above link with exact same issue

Comment: Thanks, @nima I forget to add [] in useffect

Answer (score -2):

So from what I have understood is that you are setting the data setData() which is basically state of the parent component which is returning this navbar.

so now each time navbar mounts effect is called, setData is called again which updates parent state and it rerenders the parent hence rerendering navbar again and the cycle goes on.

solution:
move up the state to the parent and pass it to navbar so navbar expects a tag prop and will just then render it.